# Заменить все символы на пробелы

Tags: c++

Я считываю строку, состоящую из чисел, разделенных различными символами, как удалить из строки все символы, заменив их на пробелы. (хочу посчитать сумму этих чисел в конечном итоге). Ограничу условия - числа целые, но могут быть отрицательными, примеры входных последовательностей : "1,2,._3" Итог суммы : 6

Comment: Считайте всю строку, замените нечисловые символы, загоните строку в stringstream, прочитайте из него числа.

Comment: Какие числа, откуда считываете, какой-то один разделитель или все разные?

Comment: @VladD вот в этом и вопрос, как все нечисловые символы заменить, учитывая, что в строке могут быть отрицательные и дробные

Comment: @John: А как отличить дефис-как-минус от дефиса-как-разделителя?

Comment: @VladD если слева цифра, то это разделитель. Хотя это не больше, чем догадки :) Автора надо вопрос заставить отредактировать, чтобы задача была полной и понятной! Это вот Harry готов на догадках ответы строчить, но таких тут немного.

Comment: @alexolut Добавьте любимое выражение про сбор репы :)

Comment: @Harry нет смысла упоминать очевидное :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если это `char*` -

```
for(char * c = s; *c; ++s)
    if (!isdigit(*c)) *c = ' ';
```

Если это строка `string` - то, в принципе, так же:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    if (!isdigit(s[i])) s[i] = ' ';
```

**Update**
Ага, раз вопрос **не** в замене всех символов на пробелы (см. заголовок вопроса), то вот другое решение:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string s = "123vbn12g12hj321.nb3jk.123-ftfy21tf-1.3e2bjh";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << s << endl;

    istringstream is(s);
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(double x;;)
    {
        is >> x;
        if (!is.fail())
        {
            cout << "get " << x << endl;
            sum += x;
            continue;
        }
        if (is.eof()) break;
        is.clear();
        is.ignore(1);
    }
    cout << sum << endl;

}
```

Comment: А если числа дробные?

Comment: или же отрицательные?

Comment: См. исправленный ответ.

Comment: @Harry с такой строкой работать не будет : "1,_,3"

Comment: @John ну замените `is.good()` на `!is.fail()`.

Comment: @Harry c этим сглупил) а если последовательность такого типа "1--3"

Comment: А что такое в арифметике `--3`, как не `+3`?

Comment: @Harry возможно ли, чтобы это тут не применялось, чтобы "--3" первый минус отбрасывался ?

Comment: Можно предварительно обработать строку (наподобие показанного в ответе в начале подхода) и заменить все последовательности из нескольких `-` одним (например, заменив первые минусы пробелами). Это достаточно просто, попробуйте самостоятельно :)

Comment: @Harry, а я sscanf присобачил :)

Comment: @John, о! в моём варианте отбрасывается первый минус :)

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/QDatJA

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  char s[256], *p;
  int x;
  int n;

  fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);

  // add n after check p to allow last iteration when the number is at the end
  for (p=s; sscanf(p, "%*[^-0-9]%n", &(n=0)), sscanf(p+=n, "%d%n", &x, &(n=0)), *p; p+=n)
    if (n)
      printf("%d ", x);
    else
      ++p; // skip '-'

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: первое, что выкатили мне - а дробные? :)

Comment: @Harry, `int x` -> `double x` && `[^-0-9]` -> `[^-0-9.]` && `%d` -> `%f` или `%lf` && `// skip '-'` -> `// skip '-' or '.'`. Вроде должно заработать?

Comment: А `1.23e-4`? :)

Comment: @Harry, то `e` туда же. А вообще, можно вообще весь первый sscanf выкинуть и инкрементиться по одному. UPDATE: А вообще стоп. Оно и так должно нормально работать. Или хочешь сказать, что его надо поделить на `1.23` и `-4`? Тогда `%g`. UPDATE2: Или `scasnf` так не работает? UPDATE3: У тебя же так же как у меня работает?

Comment: Да нет, вроде должно... я не проверял, это так, чисто теоретические мысли.

Comment: @Harry, я твои мысли так и не понял, т. к. у нас с тобой работает одинаково: твоё https://ideone.com/iWGzbV `1.2e-3e.5e+7+8-9.7.7
get 0.0012
get 5e+06
get 8
get -9.7
get 0.7
5e+06` и моё https://ideone.com/X7CMfP `0.001200 5000000.000000 8.000000 -9.700000 0.700000`.